# CSS Attribute Selector doesn't work

Tags: css, css-selectors

I try to select the red-colored paragraph and apply border to it. Why this piece of code is not working?

```css
p[color="red"] {
      border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<p style="color: green;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae, provident, nam, et, consectetur molestiae aspernatur ratione placeat dignissimos odio cum non eveniet adipisci voluptas doloribus fugiat maiores odit sint repellat.</p>
<p style="color: yellow;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae, provident, nam, et, consectetur molestiae aspernatur ratione placeat dignissimos odio cum non eveniet adipisci voluptas doloribus fugiat maiores odit sint repellat.</p>
<p style="color: lime;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae, provident, nam, et, consectetur molestiae aspernatur ratione placeat dignissimos odio cum non eveniet adipisci voluptas doloribus fugiat maiores odit sint repellat.</p>
<p style="color: darkgray;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae, provident, nam, et, consectetur molestiae aspernatur ratione placeat dignissimos odio cum non eveniet adipisci voluptas doloribus fugiat maiores odit sint repellat.</p>
<p style="color: red;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae, provident, nam, et, consectetur molestiae aspernatur ratione placeat dignissimos odio cum non eveniet adipisci voluptas doloribus fugiat maiores odit sint repellat.</p>
<p style="color: cyan;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae, provident, nam, et, consectetur molestiae aspernatur ratione placeat dignissimos odio cum non eveniet adipisci voluptas doloribus fugiat maiores odit sint repellat.</p>
<p style="color: indigo;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae, provident, nam, et, consectetur molestiae aspernatur ratione placeat dignissimos odio cum non eveniet adipisci voluptas doloribus fugiat maiores odit sint repellat.</p>
```

Am I missing something?

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kLx1gcq0/

Comment: color is not an HTML attribute

Comment: Yes, you're using an attribute selector to try and access an attribute's property. You can't target an element using its `style` attribute value. For example, the correct 'selector' would be: `p['style="color: red"']`.

Comment: It's better to use classes for this kind of things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[]` is a attribute selector, so you would have to select the `style` attribute like:

```
p[style*="color: red"] {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Lb129536/)
`*=` selects the element if the attribute contains the string specified. An excellent article about CSS selectors can [be found here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048).

That works, but only if there is a whitespace. If you don't know if it will have a whitespace or not, you could do it like:

```
p[style*="color: red"],
p[style*="color:red"] {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The selector `p[color="red"]` isn't working because the element doesn't have a `color` attribute. Since you're trying to match based on the `style` attribute, your selector could be:

[**Example Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/2h4u1fdf/)

```
p[style="color: red;"] {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

However, it's worth mentioning that this will match the attribute's value *exactly*, so it likely won't work all the time. You could match based on whether the value *contains* `color: red`:

```
p[style*="color: red"] {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

However, that may not work if whitespace varies or if the value is `background-color: red`. Of course you could select all the different variants, but if you can, I would highly suggest avoid using the attribute selector like this. Classes are better suited for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work since *color* is not an HTML attribute, which is what `[color=...]` matches against.

In general, inline styling is deprecated. You should use CSS for styling and the common practice is to use classes.

Try this instead:

```css
p.red {
      color: red;
      border: 1px solid black;
}
p.green {
      color: green;
}
p.yellow {
      color: yellow;
}
p.lime {
      color: lime;
}
```

```html
<p class="green">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae, provident, nam, et, consectetur molestiae aspernatur ratione placeat dignissimos odio cum non eveniet adipisci voluptas doloribus fugiat maiores odit sint repellat.</p>
<p class="yellow">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae, provident, nam, et, consectetur molestiae aspernatur ratione placeat dignissimos odio cum non eveniet adipisci voluptas doloribus fugiat maiores odit sint repellat.</p>
<p class="lime">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae, provident, nam, et, consectetur molestiae aspernatur ratione placeat dignissimos odio cum non eveniet adipisci voluptas doloribus fugiat maiores odit sint repellat.</p>
<p class="red">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae, provident, nam, et, consectetur molestiae aspernatur ratione placeat dignissimos odio cum non eveniet adipisci voluptas doloribus fugiat maiores odit sint repellat.</p>
```

Comment: Really, this doesn't answer the question. You give the reason it doesn't work, but no solution. The OP may have reasons for adding the styles inline, even though it isn't good practice. You should provide an answer, then if you so choose, add an alternate method. If your "answer" doesn't really contain an answer, it should be a comment.

Comment: @JacobGray - The answer is right there in the first sentence (the question is *why isn't this working...*). The solution and recommendation are what I think is important to mention regarding the issue. Of course you have the right to think otherwise...

Comment: Didn't downvote this btw. You still didn't give a solution to the problem he asked, which I at least think you should. Imho.

Comment: @JacobGray - Again, in my opinion, this is the correct solution. If someone asks about a problem when using an anti-pattern, a good answer would be to indicate that this is an anti-pattern and show how to properly approach the issue.

Comment: @JacobGray - And regarding downvotes, I'm used to it. Very few answers *don't* get random unexplained downvotes. Some people enjoy ruining SO for others :-/

Comment: @Amit +1 to counter that downvote.. Same thing happened on my answer. I highly suggest avoiding the usage of attribute selectors on the `style` attribute for the reason I pointed out in my answer. Classes, as you suggest, is clearly the better alternative, and your answer was the only other one that suggested doing so.. 1+

Comment: @JoshCrozier: *to counter* is a bad phrase (people don't like it around here) but your point is spot on and I think both your and Amit's answers are very valid (and deserve my vote :)).

Comment: @Amit: It (DV) does happen because sometimes users read only the code and think your code is not what they expected to see. I am not saying that it is correct but what I tend to do in situations like these is have two bold headings - first which says what is reason why OP's code is not working and second which says this is the suggested alternate because what they try do is wrong. I've seen that it helps and maybe it can for you too :)

Answer (score 0):

The attribute selectors are designed to identify HTML attributes, not CSS properties.  The following may work however <s>(untested)</s>:

```css
p[style*="color: red;"] {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<p style="color: green;">Green text</p>
<p style="color: yellow;">Yellow text</p>
<p style="color: lime;">Lime text</p>
<p style="color: darkgray;">Dark gray text</p>
<p style="color: red;">Red text</p>
<p style="color: cyan;">Cyan text</p>
<p style="color: indigo;">Indigo text</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The selector is wrong. p[color="red"] means "a P element that have an attribute "color" with a value of "red"... but you have "style" attribute, not "color".

Take a look to css selectors: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors

Answer (score -1):

Yeah, so simple mistake. Obviously, color is not an html attribute.

Working solutions:

```
p[style*="color"][style*="red"] {
  border: 1px solid black;
}   

p[style*="color: red"],
p[style*="color:red"] {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Special, thanks to **Jacob Gray**

Comment: To be fair, `color` was an actual attribute for the outdated `<font>` tag, and is not supported in HTML5. Just a random bit of info. Also, if you get an answer to your question (Yippee!), you should mark it as accepted, not post an answer to your own question with the same information :D